# Upload to S3 via Jenkins fails

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

When executing a script that is supposed to upload a database backup to 
S3 bucket, it fails with "Unable to locate credentials" error

AWS configured properly on the machine container:

```
oot@19e1ed41f9e9 /]# aws configure list
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************YJBG shared-credentials-file
secret_key     ****************HJ1g shared-credentials-file
    region                us-east-2      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

Script code:

```sh
#/bin/bash

DATE=$(date +%H-%M-%S)
BACKUP=db-$DATE.sql

DB_HOST=$1
DB_PASSWORD=$2
DB_NAME=$3
AWS_SECRET=$4
BUCKET_NAME=$5


mysqldump -u root -h $DB_HOST  -p$DB_PASSWORD $DB_NAME > /tmp/$BACKUP  && \
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY=AKIA5PJHRGVMJTI6YJBG && \
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET && \
echo "Uploading $BACKUP" && \
aws s3 cp /tmp/db-$DATE.sql s3://$BUCKET_NAME/$BACKUP
```

The AWS_SECRET is a key that is pulled from the "Secret Text" on Jenkins

The command in the shell on Jenkins is:

```
   /tmp/script.sh $MYSQL_HOST $MYSQL_PASS $DATABASE_NAME $AWS_SECRET $AWS_BUCKET_NAME
```

The expected result is a successful upload that does work when running the script directly inside the machine container:

```
[root@19e1ed41f9e9 tmp]# ./script.sh db-host XXX testdb XXX study2019john
Uploading db-07-28-59.sql
upload: ./db-07-28-59.sql to s3://study2019john/db-07-28-59.sql
```

The output on the console of the build is:

```
    Running as SYSTEM
    Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/backup-to-aws
    [SSH] script:
    MYSQL_HOST="db-host"
    MYSQL_PASS=**********
    DATABASE_NAME="testdb"
    AWS_BUCKET_NAME="study2019john"
    AWS_SECRET=**********

    /tmp/script.sh $MYSQL_HOST $MYSQL_PASS $DATABASE_NAME $AWS_SECRET $AWS_BUCKET_NAME 

    [SSH] executing...
    upload failed: ../../tmp/db-07-00-10.sql to s3://study2019john/db-07-00-10.sql Unable to locate credentials
    Uploading db-07-00-10.sql

    [SSH] completed
    [SSH] exit-status: 1

    Build step 'Execute shell script on a remote host using ssh' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Thx in advance

Comment: Hi John, please show us your pipeline code

Answer (score 0):

If it do works for you locally,but not from jenkins run,i have to bet that you success to uploads using your root user which is probably well configured aws_cli . try to run the script as a jenkins user for debugging

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the waste of time but in the script I have exported AWS_ACCESS_KEY instead of AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID which lead to the key not being located.

10 hours of debugging for this kind mistake.... meh

Thx anyway